# Batch processing with celery?

Tags: celery, batch-processing

I am using celery to process and deploy some data and I would like to be able to send this data in batches.

I found this:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.contrib.batches.html

But I am having problems with it, such as:

- It does not play nicely with eventlets, putting exceptions in the log
  files stating that the timer is null after the queue is empty.
- It seems to leave additional hanging threads after calling `celery
  multi stop`
- It does not appear to adhere to the standard logging of a typical
  `Task`.
- It does not appear to retry the task when `raise mytask.retry()` is
  called.

I am wondering if others have experienced these problems, and is there a solution?

I am fine with implementing batch processing on my own, but I do not know a good strategy to make sure that *all* items are deployed (i.e. even those at the end of the thread).

Also, if the batch fails, I would want to retry the entire batch. I am not sure of any elegant way to do that.

Basically, I am looking for any viable solution for doing real batch processing with celery.

I am using Celery v3.0.21

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find out something? Celery Batches is experimental, and noone is working on it. It would be really awesome if someone had the time to do that :)

Comment: I didn't, but I managed to find a way to make it work for my particular use-case. It's messy and not something I would want to release, but if you have a specific question I might be able to help.

Comment: Have you tried celery Chunks? http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chunks